# Perl: Constant value in hash-key

Tags: perl, hash, constants

I am a bit astonished. If I use a constant for a hash-key Perl does not use the value. I need to put & in front of it to make this happen.

```
use constant A => "a";
use constant B => "b";

my %h = (A => "1", &B => "2");

print "\n". A . ", " . B;
foreach (sort (keys (%h)))
{
    print "\n"  . $_ . "=" . $h {$_};
}
```

Output:

```
a, b
A=1
b=2
```

But I would expect that (2nd line is different).

```
a, b
a=1
b=2
```

Any way to do it without the & when use the constant for a hash-key??

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's documented in [constant](http://p3rl.org/constant) under CAVEATS.

The common way is to use `()`:

```
my %h = (A => "1", B() => "2");
```

or switch to the "non-stringifying fat comma" (or a simple comma):

```
my %h = (A => "1", B ,=> "2");
```

Using `&` doesn't inline the constant, as you can verify with [B::Deparse](http://p3rl.org/B::Deparse):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse ~/1.pl
sub B () { 'b' }
use constant ('A', 'a');
use constant ('B', 'b');
my(%h) = ('A', '1', &B, '2');
print "\na, b";
foreach $_ (sort keys %h) {
    print "\n" . $_ . '=' . $h{$_};
}
/home/choroba/1.pl syntax OK
```

Comment: I use `(B)` (compiles to `"b"`) instead of `B()` (compiles to a slower sub call, and requires knowing that constants can be used as subs even when they aren't subs).

Comment: @ikegami: Deparse shows B() compiled to 'b' the same way as `(B)`. Concise shows a small difference, though: `s*/FOLD` vs. `sP*/FOLD`, which I don't understand. Terse shows no diff.

Comment: Ah ok. Still, requires treating a constant as a sub, which is yucky, and requires internal knowledge.

Comment: It's the documented workaround, but I like yours more.